# How to parse the output of a Suds Client Request

Tags: python, suds

If I print the answer of my request I get the following:

```
(reply){
   returnCode = "OK"
   voucher_code = "123456"
   voucher_type = "Reloadable"
   voucher_status = "ok"
 }
```

How can I parse this?

I found an solution with `client.last_received()` but I don't know if this will be problematic with many requests at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to parse anything. Suds already did it. Just access attributes of the object that you've printed.